# Default visual studio always create event handlers in the same file - Form1.cs, how to change location?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, events

I'm just wondering if anyone had annoying default automatic event handler function creating. For example, I'm creating button event automatically, by double click on event tab (lightning tab) for double click event - visual studio automatically generates event handler in Form1.cs file. But if I want to move this event handler to another file (but in the same object and same namespace), let's say called ButtonEvents.cs (partial Form1 class), visual studio automatically generates another empty event handler in Form1.cs file. Visual studio doesn't understand, that event handler already exists, but when compiling, it send error, so every time I have to delete these default event handlers - this is very annoying....

Thank You Guys.

Comment: Why dont you just set up your own instead of using the automatic creation?

Comment: In your preferred world, how does the code to subscribe to the event know which object the event handler is in? Probably the biggest advantage to the Designer's approach is that it subscribes to the events from _within_ the object containing the code that does that initialization, making it trivial to know and understand what object reference contains the event handler.

Comment: I use automatic, because I think it is the quicker way of doing this... I don't need to go to another file, type by hand function names and so on... If I use 50 events which jumps to the same method, I should look for 50 places to change... For real I don't know why I use automatic, it's just habit I guess...

Comment: The most interesting thing, that I use the same class in different files (use partial class in the same namespace), so I guess visual studio could know where my code exists, especially, that it finds all references to that event method, but after some time it renew default event handling function, even I change it and creates new handler function in the same place...

Comment: @JonasLinze have you managed to find a way to tell VS that the event handler is located in a different file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set every method you want to handling events of your control. for example:

```
Button1.Click += new EventHandler(AnotherClass.GreetingBtn_Click);
```

If you want when you double click on your button editor shows *AnotherClass.GreetingBtn_Click* method, try to change event handler of your button in YourForm.Designer file (I'm not sure about it).

Comment: but if it is in the same partial class, I think it should understand, that it could be in another file...